# Sending GZIP json using Pika and RabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq, gzip, pika

I am currently generating a json which I am sending over RabbitMQ. However it suffers with a limit of 128 MB and my json messages are more than 500 MB. The only feasible step is moving forward with sending the gzip version of the file. Howvever I am not able to find proper documentation to do so using PIKA, python and RabbitMQ

I have tried Encoding and Decoding the Json and sending a message. But technically it would same as sending the message via JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has standard library for [gzip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html)

```py
import json
import gzip

data: dict = get_data(...)
data_bytes = json.dumps(data).encode()
compressed = gzip.compress(data_bytes)
send(compressed)

# ... sending the data over AMQP

compressed = receive(...)
decompressed = gzip.decompress(compressed)
data_decompressed = json.loads(decompressed.decode())

assert data == data_decompressed
```